# Why is my nohup.out empty?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I have a simple python script that just runs an infinite while loop and prints "running". When I start it up with nohup in the background, I see a nohup.out file in my current directory but nothing ever gets written to it. I am confused. I have tried the following

```
nohup test.py
```

writes to nohup.out but obviously does not run in the background

```
nohup test.py &
```

runs in background but does not write to nohup.out

```
nohup test.py 2>&1 &
```

also runs in the background but does not write to nohup.out

I bet I am missing something simple. Any ideas?

Here is my python script for reference:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def main():
    print "Starting...."
    while True:
        print "running..."
        sleep(5.00)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Interestingly if I remove the "sleep (5.0)" it seems to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe your stdout is not flushed immediately, because it is not attached to a terminal. Try using

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

to flush your output.

In python3 you can use `flush=True` as an argument to the print function to do that.

```py
print("running...", flush=True)
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the case. If you take out the `sleep(5.00)` then you overwhelm the buffer and the system flushes for you. This is a generic case, and not specific to Python either.

Comment: @Mei it is very specific to Python. I was very surprise to get empty nohup file. I've never seen this before with java or bash script.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to use `nohup python -u args...` to force python to print and flush buffer for each print() call.

I believe this is due to Python's default behaviour to write to buffer first, but `nohup` doesn't trigger the buffer to be cleared.

More specific answers can be found here at https://superuser.com/questions/764479/force-output-buffer-flush-in-running-program.